# Hide UILabel without consuming any space

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know of two ways hiding a `UILabel`. I can either set the alpha to 0 or the labels property 'hidden' to YES. That is

```
// UILabel *label = ...
label.alpha = 0.0f;

// or
label.hidden = YES;
```

However in both cases the label will take space (its width and height).

Is it possible to hide a label so it wont take any vertical/horizontal space? One possible way would be to set the width/height to 0 i guess. But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean taking up space? If its hidden then you can't see it, hence it doesn't take up any space. If you totally want it of screen though I guess you can just move it outside of the screen bounds.

Comment: Then why don't you remove it using `[label removeFromSuperview];` ?

Comment: @Filip yes you can't see it but the content which comes afterwards will not move up. It looks like a gap in my view.

Comment: @Midhun i may need to unhide it again and it should be on the same position. i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You can set the frame height value to 0 to hide the label.[Using autolayout? this may be enough if you set it properly]

Without autolayout, to move the content below up and it depends on setting the frame of the contents below to new frame programatically  [change all components `y value` to `yvalue-label.height`]

Answer (score 8):

I was just having this issue and found out that you have to set the text to an empty string to get it to not take up space. (iOS 9)

```
 label.text = @"";
 label.hidden = YES;
```

iOS has so many bugs.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to handle this is using **Stack Views**. Embed the label in a stack view and stack view will internally take care of the spacing. Additional properties like alignment, spacing can be tweaked as per requirement. Make sure you re-establish the constraints between stack view and adjacent elements since once the views are added to a stack view all if its constraints are cleared

Answer (score 0):

**Hide UILabel without consuming any space**

Swift version:

```
myLabel.text = ""
myLabel.isHidden = true
```